# How to make Discord.py create different savegames for different users

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord.py bot that plays a game. So far I have gotten it to make one file for the whole system, although I want different ones for each user. I have been using pickle and I haven't been seeing a way to do this anywhere. I have been having a hard time making stuff that is specific to a user so that's also a problem. If there isn't any way to do this let me know. Here is my code so far:

````
async def SwordGame(ctx, arg):
    
    playerlevel = 1
    playerxp = 0
    playerxpneeded = 100
    enemy = ("Goblin", "Gladiator", "Vampire",
             "Zombie", "Clone of Yourself")
    chosenenemy = random.choice(enemy)
    enemyhp = 50
    swordtype = ("Gladiator", "Katana", "Scimitar", "Rapier",
                 "LongSword", "Broadsword", "Cutlass", "ShortSword")
    chosensword = random.choice(swordtype)
    swordmodifier = ("Speed", "Power")
    chosenmodifier = random.choice(swordmodifier)
    swordmagic = ("Fire", "Ice", "Lightning", "Wind", "Dark", "Toxic")
    chosenmagic = random.choice(swordmagic)
    magicpower = 100
    swordlevel = 1
    swordxp = 0
    swordxpneeded = 100
    playerhp = 100

    validgameanswers=["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
    if arg not in validgameanswers or arg == "":
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title='Sword Simulator Game',
            Description="The Sword Simulator game by MrPenguin280",
            color=discord.Color.dark_red()
            )
        choiceslist = '''
    1 = Battle
    2 = Check Sword Stats
    3 = Check Player Stats
    4 = Heal
    5 = Power up Magic
    6 = XP farm
    '''
        embed.add_field(name='Choices:\n', value=choiceslist)
        embed.add_field(name='What do you choose?', value="Do &sg **numberchosen** to choose")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    
    with open('savefilesword.dat', 'rb') as f:
        chosensword, swordmodifier, chosenmodifier, chosenmagic, magicpower, swordlevel, swordxp, swordxpneeded, playerhp, playerlevel, playerxp, playerxpneeded, chosenenemy, enemyhp = pickle.load(f)
    if arg in validgameanswers:
        if arg == "1":
            if playerlevel >= 2:
                playerhp += 50
            if playerlevel >= 3:
                playerhp += 50
            if playerlevel >= 4:
                playerhp += 50
            if playerlevel >= 5:
                playerhp += 50
            def check(message):
                return message.content in ['1', '2'] and message.author != client.user
            await ctx.send("You chose to battle")
            await ctx.send(f"A {chosenenemy} Walks into the stadium. You ready your sword")
            while enemyhp > 0:
                await ctx.send("Type 1 to do a normal battle or 2 to use your magic power")
                aora = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=20)
                attackorability = aora.content
                if attackorability == "1":
                    enemyhitordodged=random.randint(1,3)
                    if enemyhitordodged == 1 or enemyhitordodged == 3:
                        damage=random.randint(10,20)
                        if swordlevel == 2:
                            damage += 10
                        elif swordlevel == 3:
                            damage += 20
                        elif swordlevel == 4:
                            damage += 30
                        elif swordlevel == 5:
                            damage += 40
                        await ctx.send(f"You hit! You did {damage} to the {chosenenemy}")
                        enemyhp-=damage
                    elif enemyhitordodged == 2:
                        await ctx.send(f"The {chosenenemy} Dodged the attack!")
                    playerhitordodged = random.randint(1,3)
                    if playerhitordodged == 1 or playerhitordodged == 3:
                        await ctx.send("You Dodged! You lost 0 hp")
                    elif playerhitordodged == 2:
                        damagetoplayer = random.randint(5,10)
                        playerhp -= damagetoplayer
                        await ctx.send(f"The {chosenenemy} did {damagetoplayer} to you!")
                elif attackorability == "2":
                    if magicpower == 0:
                        await ctx.send("You Do Not Have Enough MPP!")
                    else:
                        await ctx.send("You Used up 50 MPP to do 30 damage to the enemy and stunned them so they could not attack")
                        enemyhp -= 30
                        magicpower -= 50
                        if magicpower < 0:
                            magicpower = 0
                        await ctx.send(f"You Have {magicpower} MPP left")
            if enemyhp <= 0:
                await ctx.send(f"You Killed the {chosenenemy}!")
                swordxp += 30
                playerxp += 20
                if swordxp >= 100 and swordlevel != 5:
                    await ctx.send("Sword Level Up!")
                    swordlevel += 1
                if playerxp >= 100 and playerlevel != 5:
                    await ctx.send("Player Level Up!")
            with open('savefilesword.dat', 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump([chosensword, swordmodifier, chosenmodifier, chosenmagic, magicpower, swordlevel, swordxp, swordxpneeded, playerhp, playerlevel, playerxp, playerxpneeded, chosenenemy, enemyhp], f, protocol=2)



        if arg == "2":
            await ctx.send("Here are your sword stats\n")
            swordstats="\t\t\t\t____________________\n"
            swordstats+="\t\t\t\t|Player Sword Stats|\n"
            swordstats+=f"Your Sword is: {chosensword}\n"
            swordstats+=f"Your Sword Modifier is: {chosenmodifier}\n"
            swordstats+=f"Your Sword Magic is: {chosenmagic}\n"
            swordstats+=f"Your Sword Skill Level is: {swordlevel}\n"
            swordstats+=f"Your Sword XP amount is: {swordxp}/{swordxpneeded}"
            await ctx.send(swordstats)
            with open('savefile.dat', 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump([chosensword, swordmodifier, chosenmodifier, chosenmagic, magicpower, swordlevel, swordxp, swordxpneeded, playerhp, playerlevel, playerxp, playerxpneeded, chosenenemy, enemyhp], f, protocol=2)
        if arg == "3":
            await ctx.send("Here are your player stats\n")
            playerstats = "\t\t\t\t______________\n"
            playerstats += "\t\t\t\t|Player stats|\n"
            playerstats += f"Player HP left is: {playerhp}\n"
            playerstats += f"Player MPP left is: {magicpower}\n"
            playerstats += f"Player Level is: {playerlevel}\n"
            playerstats += f"Player XP amount is : {playerxp}/{playerxpneeded}"
            await ctx.send(playerstats)
            with open('savefile.dat', 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump([chosensword, swordmodifier, chosenmodifier, chosenmagic, magicpower, swordlevel, swordxp, swordxpneeded, playerhp, playerlevel, playerxp, playerxpneeded, chosenenemy, enemyhp], f, protocol=2)
        if arg == "4":
            if playerhp <= 99:
                await ctx.send("You Healed by 40 HP")
                playerhp += 40
                if playerhp >= 100:
                    playerhp = 100
            else:
                await ctx.send("You are at max HP")
            with open('savefile.dat', 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump([chosensword, swordmodifier, chosenmodifier, chosenmagic, magicpower, swordlevel, swordxp, swordxpneeded, playerhp, playerlevel, playerxp, playerxpneeded, chosenenemy, enemyhp], f, protocol=2)
        if arg == "5":
            if magicpower <=199:
                await ctx.send("You Powered up your magic by 50 points")
                magicpower += 50
                if magicpower >= 200:
                    magicpower = 200
            else:
                await ctx.send("You are at max Magic Power")
            with open('savefile.dat', 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump([chosensword, swordmodifier, chosenmodifier, chosenmagic, magicpower, swordlevel, swordxp, swordxpneeded, playerhp, playerlevel, playerxp, playerxpneeded, chosenenemy, enemyhp], f, protocol=2)
        if arg == "6":
            ctx.send("You chose to wait to gain XP for 1 minute")
            time.sleep(60)
            playerxp += playerxpneeded
            swordxp += swordxpneeded
            ctx.send("You Leveled up after waiting!")
            playerlevel += 1
            playerxp = 0
            swordlevel += 1
            swordxp = 0
            with open('savefile.dat', 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump([chosensword, swordmodifier, chosenmodifier, chosenmagic, magicpower, swordlevel, swordxp, swordxpneeded, playerhp, playerlevel, playerxp, playerxpneeded, chosenenemy, enemyhp], f, protocol=2)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also making a game for my discord bot. For this, I use dictionaries stored in files named after the users' IDs, since they're really easy to access via `ctx.author.id` and will never change. When a user activates a command, I unpickle the file named `f"{ctx.author.id}.dat"` and assign the dictionary that was stored inside to a variable. I can then modify the dictionary values by accessing them via their keys and can pickle the dictionary again after I'm done.

Using this method, I can also easily check if a user does not have an assigned save file yet using `os.path.isfile(f"{ctx.author.id}.dat")` and can pickle a template dictionary into their file.

Also, `time.sleep()` should not be used together with asynchronous code.

Comment: so if i were to do this, would I need to make if statements asking if the file was already made or is there a different way to do this

edit: Wait nvm i figured it out